# Discord.js: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bot')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Working on a bot that checks if certain words are present in a bot search.  First it gets the reference (if there is one), and then checks the message in an array of words.  It works 99.9% of the time, but 0.1% I get this message:

```
node:events:489
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bot')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\index.js:235:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_UPDATE] (C:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_UPDATE.js:14:12)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1173:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (C:\Bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:988:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

The code in question:

```
    const command2 = message.content
    if(`${message.author.id}`=== "(BOT ID)") {
        if (message.reference !== "") {
        const imgSearch = await message.fetchReference()
        const forbiddenSearches = ["forbidden", "messages", "here"];
            for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenSearches.length; i++) {
            if (imgSearch.content.includes(forbiddenSearches[i])) {
            message.delete();
            imgSearch.channel.send(`${imgSearch.author.username} searched "${imgSearch.content}"`)
            console.log(`${imgSearch.author.username} searched "${imgSearch.content}"`);
            //break; (USED TO HAVE THIS BUT I DECIDED IT DIDNT NEED IT)
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Apparently this is also whats causing the issue, another piece of code:

```
client.on('messageUpdate', async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    if (!newMessage.embeds[0]) return;                   //THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
    if(newMessage.author.bot) return;
    if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) return;
    if (newMessage.partial) await newMessage.fetch(true);
    //some stuff
});
```

Like I previously stated it works 15 times in a row and then out of the blue crashes the bot.

Comment: there is no even 'bot' identifier in this code, also you didn't tell us in which line the error is

Comment: As for the bot identifier, I use message.author.bot elsewhere in the code, but definitely not where its crashing.  As for the line of the error, Im not sure how to find it.  I did update the error log though to provide more information.

Comment: According to the error you posted, it occures at `at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\index.js:235:26)` (index.js line 235)

Comment: huh, so its at "if (!newMessage.embeds[0]) return;"  Thats weird, Ill see if this has caused issues with anyone else.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the index.js, as it might be there..? @JamesLewis

Comment: Im now sure it has to do with the bot updating some piece of code therefore triggering the other function, and have switched the places of line 235 and 236 to exclude bots from receiving this command.  I think what happened here was that because it was a bot it has different properties.  Very cool, thanks for the info, I was wondering how to get the line of the error code!

Comment: Last question, (because people have downvoted this post), what could I have done as someone new to js?  From my knowledge at the time of post I had provided all the relevant details, and researched a thousand more issues trying to get to the bottom of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apprently the code of your conditional if check generates the error. The code line is:

```js
if(newMessage.author.bot) return;
```

Here the property `author` is null and has no property of `bot`, thus we get the correspoing error.

I'm not sure if this is a big problem and every `author` property must not be a `null` value but I think that if this only happens rarely (1 in 1000) then you can easily avoid these cases by using optional chaining(`?.`) in JavaScript:

```js
if(newMessage.author?.bot) return;
```

Optional chaining is short-hand for this code:

```js
if(newMessage.author && newMessage.author.bot) return;
```

This way you first check if `author` property is a truthy value (here, we are expecting an object with property `bot`, so for these cases it is truthy and if the value is `null` is then it is falsy) thus we will prevent errors being generates due to `author` property is null.

This will solve the problem for those rare exceptions but with more inspectation regarding the cause/source of the problem, you can ensure that `author` field is always an object with appropriate `bot` property. By doing so, you will also eliminate those rare exceptions occuring.